# Connecting to SQL Server using shared memory and jtds driver

Tags: sql-server-2000, shared-memory, windows-server-2012, tcp, jtds

I have a java application which connects to SQL Server 2000 using jtds driver. It is working fine on *Windows Server 2003*. The connection string I used here is as below

con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/DBName", info );

Now I am trying to run the same application on *Windows server 2012.* But the problem here is, SQL server 2000 is not listening to TCP Port 1433, but it is listening to shared memory. Hence it fails the connection.

I tried to enable TCP/IP Protocol as mentioned in workaround section in this link [Enabling TCP/IP Through the Server Network Utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308766). SQL server didn't start listening to TCP/IP even after restarting the server.

To solve this problem, either I have to make SQL server listen to TCP/IP port or I need to change my code to connect using shared memory if Server is not listening to TCP/IP port.

I am trying to connect to server using shared memory with below connection string as mentioned in this page [Creating a Valid Connection String Using Shared Memory Protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187662(v=sql.105).aspx)

con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433/DBName", info );

Which leads to the exception 
*java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'.*

I also tried the connection string:

con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS/DBName", info );

which produces the exception: 
*java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'.*

It would be great if I can get solution for either of the problems

1. Enabling TCP/IP port on Windows server 2012 for SQL server 2000
2. Connecting to SQL server 2000 using shared memory protocol in jtds driver.

Thanks in advance,
Jayanth

Comment: It's beyond time to consider upgrading SQL Server. Beyond the fact that SQL Server 2000 fell out of support a long time ago, the last supported Windows OS that it was supported on was Windows Server 2003 - which has also fallen out of support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for one of those 2 problems - Enabling TCP/IP port on Windows server 2012 for SQL server 2000.

1. Launch SVRNETCN.exe in the path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn”
2. Select TCP/IP from Disabled protocols list and click on Enable
3. Make sure the default port is set to 1433 for TCP/IP protocol by clicking on properties button